# Checking Checksum of a file from a url

Tags: ansible

I want to check the sha1 hash of file from a url.

```
- name: Download CONF WEB/WS/CORE files
  get_url:
    url: "{{ file.url }}"
    checksum: "sha1:{{ file.url }}.sha1"
    dest: "/home/file"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    url_username: "xxxx"
    url_password: "xxxxx"
    mode: 0640
    timeout: 300
    force: yes
```

i have a file located in http://domaine.com/file
and the checksum located in http://domaine.com/file.sha1

when i execute the playbook i get this error message:

```
The checksum parameter has to be in format <algorithm>:<checksum> the example in ansible documentation is as below:
```

Ansible documentation :
If a checksum is passed to this parameter, the digest of the destination
 file will be calculated after it is downloaded to ensure its integrity and
 verify that the transfer completed successfully. ***Format: 
:, e.g. checksum="sha256:D98291AC[...]B6DC7B97", 
checksum="sha256:http://example.com/path/sha256sum.txt"***

Did someone encountered the same errors
Thanks for your help in advance ^^,

Comment: I just tried the [algorithm:url] format and it now works. So it seems that in the 4 years since this question was asked, the implementation has caught up to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this comment it seems they won't provide such feature to check the checksum against an URL
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48790#issuecomment-440432038

It seems you need to do it in two separated tasks, one to download the checksum file and a second task to extract the checksum value from the downloaded file

I did this

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Download file
    get_url:
      url: "http://localhost/file"
      checksum: "sha1:3b71f43ff30...e84eb5a3"
      dest: "/home/user/file"
```

and it worked

> Related issues
>   https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27617
>   https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48790
>   https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48847

Comment: thanks ^_^, in this case they should remove it from the documentation it's misleading

Comment: I agree, actually you can propose a change in the docs here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/get_url.py

Comment: tried installing `hashlib` as suggested in the doc and didn't work :'(